# How do I pass a JSON object from JSP to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a variable for myInitState that is initialized within a controller that is then passed to a jsp view.

```
<script>
    myInitFunction({ 
        myInitState: '${myInitState}',
        componentName: 'myCompName',
        divId: 'divId'        
    });
</script>
```

However by using `'${myInitState}'`, in my Javascript I notice I get a string of "{...}" when debugging in browser. Is it possible to pass the object as json and have it be recognized as such or would I have re-parse the object within `myInitFunction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to take advantage of string interpolation, you need to use backticks

> `${myInitState}`

You will then want to parse the string inside the function using `JSON.parse(someString)`

Comment: I swapped to backticks, however I notice client side it is still received as a string, as opposed to an actual JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer here:
A couple of things I had left out of my question due to my misunderstanding:
 - myInitState is a Map of `<String,Object>`
 - The values of the map could be already escaped JSON blobs.

In this case the flow was from Server to client, so in order to convert the map into a JSON blob correctly I would need to do something like this in JSP:

```
<script>
    var jsonBlob = {
        <c:forEach items="${myInitState}" var="state" varStatus="loop">
            "${state.key}": ${state.value} ${not loop.last ? ',' : ''}
        </c:forEach>
    };
</script>
```

However, a better approach, and what I went with, would be to just do conversion in the controller itself where myInitState is constructed.